# For a given Pandas df, sort the df by a column (highest SUMMED values first) then within each unique value order by another column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

My df:

```
Test_Data = [('Client', ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B','C','C']),
             ('Currency', ['USD', 'EUR', 'USD', 'AUD', 'EUR', 'USD', 'GBP', 'USD']),
             ('SalesPerson', ['Dave', 'Dave', 'Bob', 'Dave', 'Dave', 'Bob','Dave','Bob']),
             ('Done_Trades', [1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6]),
             ('Average_Qty', [10, 50, 100, 10, 50, 1000, 50, 100]),
             ('Average_Qty_CAD', [1, 2, 3, 30,20, 10,1,2])

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Test_Data))
print(df)

  Client Currency SalesPerson  Done_Trades  Average_Qty  Average_Qty_CAD
0      A      USD        Dave            1           10                1
1      A      EUR        Dave            1           50                2
2      A      USD         Bob            2          100                3
3      B      AUD        Dave            3           10               30
4      B      EUR        Dave            3           50               20
5      B      USD         Bob            4         1000               10
6      C      GBP        Dave            5           50                1
7      C      USD         Bob            6          100                2
```

a. Client B has the highest summed Average_Qty_CAD per client (60) so it is displayed first followed by A (6) then C (3).

b. Within B, Dave has the highest Average_Qty_CAD (30), then the second (20) and Bob has the third (10) so we want B's rows ordered 30,20,10.

c. Within A, Bob has the highest Average_Qty_CAD (3), then Dave's two entries  (2,1) so we want A ordered 3,2,1.

d. Within C, Bob has the highest Average_Qty_CAD (1002, then Dave (1) so order 2, 1

Also if I wanted the sum of each clients Average_Qty_CAD displayed what need to be added?

Desired df:

```
  Client Currency SalesPerson  Done_Trades  Average_Qty  Average_Qty_CAD Total per Client
2      B      AUD        Dave            3           10               30  60
1      B      EUR        Dave            3           50               20  60
0      B      USD         Bob            4         1000               10  60
3      A      USD         Bob            2          100                3  6
4      A      EUR        Dave            1           50                2  6
5      A      USD        Dave            1           10                1  6
6      C      USD         Bob            6          100                2  3
7      C      GBP        Dave            5           50                1  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `sum` and then [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df['Total per Client'] = df.groupby('Client')["Average_Qty_CAD"].transform('sum')
df = (df.sort_values(by=["Total per Client", "Client", "Average_Qty_CAD"], 
                         ascending=[False, True, False]))
print (df)
  Client Currency SalesPerson  Done_Trades  Average_Qty  Average_Qty_CAD  \
3      B      AUD        Dave            3           10               30   
4      B      EUR        Dave            3           50               20   
5      B      USD         Bob            4         1000               10   
2      A      USD         Bob            2          100                3   
1      A      EUR        Dave            1           50                2   
0      A      USD        Dave            1           10                1   
7      C      USD         Bob            6          100                2   
6      C      GBP        Dave            5           50                1   

   Total per Client  
3                60  
4                60  
5                60  
2                 6  
1                 6  
0                 6  
7                 3  
6                 3
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you can do something like:

```
m=(df.reindex(df.groupby('Client').Qty_CAD.transform(sum).
               sort_values(ascending=False).index).reset_index(drop=True))
print(m)
```

---

```
  Client SalesPerson  Qty_CAD
0      B         Bob    10000
1      B        Dave       50
2      B        Dave       10
3      A         Bob      100
4      A        Dave       50
5      A        Dave       10
6      C         Bob      100
7      C        Dave       50
```

Comment: Hi @anky_91, I added this solution to my larger df (which has additional columns: Currency, Number of Done Trades and Qty) Interestingly the resultant df only displays Index, Number on Done Trades, Qty and Qty_CAD. Client and Currency are omitted. Is there additional work to preserve these columns?

Comment: @PeterLucas shouldnt be the case. I tried on a test data with 2 additional columns, and successfully able to see them in the output

Comment: @PeterLucas hmm. i would suggest if you dont mind,you can ask a seperate question with the df before the previous aggregation explaining what you are doing prior to this step. :) You might get shorter responses combining the 2 steps to one.

Comment: hey @anky_91, upstream resolved, now looking to set the Totals within  each client's Average_Qty_CAD descending

Answer (score 0):

This does the job, not as elegant as I would like:

```
# Get Totals per client
aux = df.groupby('Client')["Average_Qty_CAD"].sum().rename("Total per Client").reset_index()
print(aux)
# Merge Totals per client with original df and sort
# In case of tie, you want to sort by ascending client
m = df.merge(aux).sort_values(by=["Total per Client", "Client", "Average_Qty_CAD"], ascending=[False, True, False])
print(m)
```